# Error al intentar obtener el numero total de filas en una tabla SqLite

Tags: c#

la operación es sencilla pero parece serlo  no tanto, lo que intento es obtener el numero de filas de dicha tabla:

```
private Int32 totFilas(string tabla)
    {
        comandoConsulta = conexion.CreateCommand();
        comandoConsulta.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM " + tabla; 
        Int32 cnt = (Int32)comandoConsulta.ExecuteScalar();
        return cnt;
    }
```

En teoría según lo que estado buscando por la red se hace de este modo, pero me da un error que es este:
Excepción no controlada: System.InvalidCastException: La conversión especificada no es válida

que estoy haciendo mal?,ya que los ejemplos vistos me parecen hacerlo a si

Comment: Tal vez tengas que usar `Convert.ToInt32()`

Comment: porque la transformacion?

Comment: Acabo de replicar el codigo y me funcionó correctamente

Comment: Si señor, me habia pasado por la cabeza, pero no lo recordaba con claridad,muchas gracias